# **/* doesn't include files at top level

Tags: shell, terminal, wildcard, github-actions

I have a file structure like:

- a.txt
- x/

  - b.txt
- y/

  - c.txt
  - yz/

    - d.txt

Now, I want to list through all .txt files. As far as I know `for file in **/*.txt` should do the job, right? At least it works in my zsh. But my GitHub action ignores the file a.txt on top level. Any idea of how to solve this? Or is there another easy way to do that with GH actions?

Comment: _As far as I know for file in **/*.txt should do the job, right?_ No. Some shells have it, some don't. Unless you add a specific shell's tag, how are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: `**/*.txt` includes the character `/`, so the result must include a `/`. Just do `*.txt **/*.txt` a9nd if you are working with bash, you should enable the `**` extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @KamilCuk, not all shells support the `**` extensions the same way. In my case, GitHub Actions uses `bash` as default and `bash` (apparently) doesn't include file on root level for `**/*` (unlike `zsh` e.g.)

I ended up with `for file in *.txt **/*.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The `**` is a extension that not all shells support. Use `find`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' |
while IFS= read -r file; do
     # do something with file
done
```